# NumberOfDiscIntersections timeout in codility test

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, sorting

My code passes as correct but it times out for input arrays with a very high number of intersections.

[NumberOfDiscIntersections](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/number_of_disc_intersections/)

How can I reduce the complexity of the solution and make it more efficient?

```
function solution(A) {
    let ret = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        const a = A[i];
        for(let j = i+1; j < A.length; j++){
            const b = A[j];
            if(i+a >= j-b){
                ret++;
                if(ret > 10000000){
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: ask your question here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtain the intervals:

```
A[0] = 1 -> (-1, 1)
A[1] = 5 -> (-4, 6)
A[2] = 2 -> (0, 4)
A[3] = 1 -> (2, 4)
A[4] = 4 -> (0, 8)
A[5] = 0 -> (5, 5)
```

Split and label the intervals with "start" and "end", then sort them:

```
(-4s,6e) (-1s,1e) (0s,4e) (0s,8e) (2s,4e) (5s,5e)

-4s -1s 0s 0s 1e 2s 4e 4e 5s 5e 6e 8e

s means start
e means end
```

Iterate from left to right, maintaining a count of stil-open intervals, and add the number of still-open intervals overlapping the current starting point.

```
     open  overlaps
-4s:   1     0
-1s:   2     1
 0s:   3     2
 0s:   4     3
 1e:   3
 2s:   4     3
 4e:   3
 4e:   2
 5s:   3     2
 5e:   2
 6e:   1
 8e:   0
 
 Total       11
```

Comment: Thank you. I made a script from your suggestion and it seems to work well, but it still fails in two of the Big sample performance tests, returning a negative value, which seemed impossible: https://jsfiddle.net/alotropico/w49yjmxc/3/ Any ideas?

Comment: Before the definition of 'open' and 'overlaps' variables, B has been converted to an array of arrays, in each position it contains one of the endpoints followed by a 0 (start) or 1 (end). So A[1,5,2,1,4,0] becomes B[[-4, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [4, 1], [4, 1], [5, 0], [5, 1], [6, 1], [8, 1]], but I think this should be the same as your labeled elements

Comment: The thing is it only occurs with huge arrays, it passes all other tests https://imgur.com/a/kjN4nwh

Comment: @alotropico I just tried your code converted to Python and got [100% across the board](https://imgur.com/a/uzr5Dan). Maybe they have a bug.

Comment: @alotropico I think function had to return -1 if the number of intersections > 10,000,000

Comment: In this answer, a proper explanation of iteration wouldn't hurt I guess. @גלעד ברקן?